# Extract and plot data frames from list

Tags: r, list, plot, lapply

I have a series of data files which are outputs from a model (variable number, depending on simulation parameters), each file represents an output for a given time step. I managed to import the files into R, using *lapply*, creating a list with *n* data frames on it, one for each time step.

Each data frame on the list, contains 9 columns (one with distances which is the same for all the data frames). I would like to dynamically extract the same column from each data frame in the list, put them together into a new data frame (creating 8 data frames in this case) and then use *matplot* to obtain a graphical output of my series. The desired output are 8 plots (in this case) with *n* series of the same column (mineral concentrations) plotted on it.

Since the number of output files changes depending on the simulation parameters, it has been difficult to me to automatize the process without having to update the script every time I update my model. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show how you want this to work with couple of data files as an example?

Comment: I am biased towards the `tidyverse`. If you have a list of n data frames, you can easily do `bind_rows(your_list)`. If you use `purrr` to read in the files, you can even supply the dataframe output: `map_df(your_list, bind_rows)`. A nice write up on how to manipulate lists of dataframes is http://zevross.com/blog/2019/06/11/the-power-of-three-purrr-poseful-iteration-in-r-with-map-pmap-and-imap/. This gives an example on hoe to extract same columns, etc.  Good luck!